# How should a muslim urinate according to Islam?

Tags: shafii, taharah

Whether I sit or stand, it seems like urine gets on me anyway. And it seems as if I need to urinate naked and bathe after every urination, but I'm pretty sure that's not how Muslims are supposed to do it. **According to the *Shafi'i* school, how should a Muslim urinate, and especially how should one deal with urine that splashes onto oneself?**

I think I'm just having excessive *waswas* concerning urine, I take so many precautions and I think it's most likely that urine isn't hitting my pants sometimes but I still am scared to wear the pants to *salah*.

Comment: The original version was a bit too vague to get good answers; I have taken the liberty of focussing it.  Please review to ensure I have not lost the gist of your question.

Comment: you did not lose the gist of my question.

Comment: Usually The Muslims don't have these problems because of khatna(having penile foreskin cutoff).

Comment: @ImtiazMahbubKhan Depending on how well the khatna has been done the problems can even be worse than without khatna... correcting this is sometimes impossible and when possible it is rather painfull... so: yes, this problem can absolutely happen to muslims too esp. since the khatna is often done in an unprofessional way... these problems usually show up when one gets a bit older (not in childhood).

Comment: my problem is not the khatna, my problem is that whether I sit or stand the urine seemed to **splash** on me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a perfect Fatwa [here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/199079), in arabic. I'll try to conclude in the next points:

1. The amount of splashed urine is judged as negligible unless you certainly know it is not. Please stop your waswasa.
2. The amount of wet cloth that is not negligible and should be washed is the area of you little finger tip. A drop or two will not be that big.
3. If you `saw' smaller urine droplets, it's "better" to wash this little area.
4. If you did Wodou, then had Waswas about urine splashes, DO NOT redo your wodou and don't go with your waswas.
5. If you saw some urine droplets on your trousers, and had fears if it touched any inner cloth, you should (again) stop your waswas. Doubts have no effect as your cloth are originally clean. If you sensed wetness, that's another story.

The main point: You know you have some "waswas", please ignore it and proceed.

Comment: Thanks! IslamQA also has a useful link : What should he do if he gets urine on his clothes? http://islamqa.info/en/ref/12720

Answer (score 0):

Whether you bend down, or you are on your feet, what you need to do is to beware of urine not to contact with your body or dressess. If you discover that it touches your body, you must know how you'll wipe it with little water that will multiply that amount of urine. And it's adviceable rather to bend down than to be on feet, so that the amount of urine that will get to ur body will be little, than to be on stand.

God will forgive all our sin.